# Python tkinter как сделать рамку?

Tags: python, tkinter

Вопрос, можно сделать такую же рамку как на скрине(Preview, General Options и т.д.) с помощью библиотеки Tkinter, если да то покажите пример)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, с помощью темизированных виджетов (`ttk`). Этот виджет, по крайней мере, в `TCL`, на основе которого и работает `Tkinter`, называется `labelframe`. Там есть специальный движок тем, который называется Tile. В нем можно творить что угодно, но для начала с ним придется разобраться, а документация (могу ошибаться) не полна. Для одной из встроенной тем нужный виджет выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(То есть, немного не **так**).

Код на TCL, который это рисует:

```
wm geometry . 480x320
ttk::setTheme clam
pack [ttk::labelframe .lf -text "Группа элементов"] -expand 1 -fill both -padx 20 -pady 20
```

С Python, простите, помочь не могу, но смысл моего ответа: нужный вам логически по смыслу виджет существует и через движок тем его можно привести к различным видам, в том числе, с использованием растровых текстур.